# How to avoid using CRTP Curiously recurring template pattern to enable sharing of functions

Tags: c++, crtp

I have inherited maintenance of a plot program that uses CRTP ([Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern))
to enable sharing of derived functions between classes for different dimensions.

But though using `derived().my_funct()` works on all compilers, it confuses Visual Studio Intellisense and debug, and Doxygen, so I'd like to stop using this in future.

The skeleton program below illustrates what I want to do.

The nub of the problem is hundreds of small functions to set features that are common to all dimensions - except for the reference `svg1&` or `svg2` to allow chaining with `return *this`.

I could create two include files that differ only in the `svg&`, but this would be inelegant and a maintenance nightmare.

Suggestions welcome.

```
//svg2.hpp

  #include <string>

  class svg1;
  class svg2;

  class svg1
  {
  public:
    static const int dim_ = 1;
    int size_ = 0;
    std::string title_;
    svg1(std::string title = "title")
    {
      title_ = title;
    }

    svg1& size(int s)   // Note svg1&
    {
      size_ = s;
      return *this; // Chainable.
    }

    // There are nearly 300 more chainable functions like size.

  }; // class svg1

  class svg2
  {
  public:
    static const int dim_ = 2;
    int size_ = 0;
    std::string title_;
    svg2(std::string title = "title")
    {
      title_ = title;
    }

    svg2& size(int s)   // Note svg2&, otherwise identical, so want to avoid duplicating hundreds of functions!
    {
      size_ = s;
      return *this; // Chainable.
    }
  }; // class svg2



  #include <string>

  #include "svg2.hpp"

  int main()
  {
    svg1 plot1("my_1D_title");
    plot1.size(99);

    svg2 plot2("my_2D_title");
    plot2.size(99);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, CRTP is the correct solution to this problem.

Comment: I've never seen MSVC's intellisense parser get confused by the CRTP.... I think you might want to ask a question about that instead.

Comment: The CRTP version of your example code does *not* require the `derived().my_funct()` construction but merely `return static_cast<Derived*>(this)`.